# pip install gives hash mismatch even with --no-cache-dir

Tags: python, pip

This is on Windows 10, running under a proxy, both in a clean venv and a conda environment.

I am trying to do
`pip install pyinstaller`
which gives me a Hash mismatch. It's not a pyinstaller issue since it works on a different machine. I get a different (incorrect) Hash every time, no matter what I try, even with --no-cache-dir. I don't remember what I did, but I gave pip a bad command (I think I had a typo with either my password in --proxy or in one of the URLs for --trusted-host and I ctrl+c'd to cancel it) and after that it I would always get a hash mismatch. As a quick workaround, doing `conda install pyinstaller` worked, but even after restarting my machine and trying again in a brand new venv, installing via pip won't work.

Did pip download some kind of bad certificate (because I am using --trusted-host for pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org) for pyinstaller only and whenever I try to use it I get a bad hash?

My full pip command looks as follows:

`pip install pyinstaller --proxy https://user:pass@proxy.com:8080 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`